# Find all the Vertexes which are connected to hope through all edges

Tags: gremlin

I want to find all the Vertexes which are connected to actions(with edge label allow), those are marked as critical by CriticalAction1.

The condition is that It should be connected with all the actions which are marked as critical action by CriticalAction1 vertex.

So in following image, since CriticalAction1 has 2 actions Action1 & Action2.
Node1 is connected with total 3 actions including Action1 & Action2. So it should be output result.
Node2 is connected with only 1 action. which doesn't satisfy the criteria that it should be connected with all the actions which are marked as critical by CriticalAction1.

[image]

Sample data script:

```
g.addV('Node1').as('node1'). addV('Node2').as('node2'). addV('Action1').as('action1'). addV('Action2').as('action2'). addV('Action3').as('action3'). addV('CriticalAction1').as('criticalaction1'). addE('allow').from('node1').to('action1'). addE('allow').from('node1').to('action2'). addE('allow').from('node1').to('action3'). addE('allow').from('node2').to('action1'). addE('critical action').from('criticalaction1').to('action1'). addE('critical action').from('criticalaction1').to('action2').iterate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` to store all the critical action connections and then `groupCount`
the node you found from them.

```
g.V().hasLabel('CriticalAction1').
  out('critical action').
  aggregate('actions').in('allow').
  groupCount().by().unfold().
  where(eq('actions')).
    by(select(values)).
    by(count(local)).
  select(keys)
```

example: https://gremlify.com/wn9cge4knrh

**EDIT:**

for multiple CriticalAction:

```
g.V().hasLabel('CriticalAction').project('CriticalAction', 'Nodes')
    .by(valueMap())
    .by(
      out('has critical action').fold()
      aggregate('actions').unfold().in('allow').
      groupCount().by().unfold().
      where(eq('actions')).
        by(select(values)).
        by(unfold().tail(1).count(local))
    .select(keys).valueMap().fold())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/fg2inyhnm9n

Comment: can we run this without supplying CriticalAction1?
lets assume the label is CriticalAction and it has multiple such CriticalAction1,CriticalAction2,CriticalAction3 etc.
 so it means evaluates for all such CriticalActions and return [CriticalAction , Node]

Comment: I have added 1 another ciritcalaction and it stopped working. because I think it aggregates and makes a count as 3.
https://gremlify.com/kbac9y1hlf

Comment: @KishanGajjar try this: https://gremlify.com/fg2inyhnm9n